# How to use a pytest fixture to instantiate a object under test?

Tags: object, pytest, instantiation, fixtures

It appears that fixtures should be used to instantiate an object under test for pytest, especially if it is used by several test_ functions. However, after trying to adapt examples given in the pytest doc, I cannot get the following to work.

```
import pytest
...
@pytest.fixture
def newMyClass():
    obj = MyClass(1,2)

...
def test_aMethod(newMyClass):
    objectUnderTest = newMyClass.obj
    ...
```

There are no complaints about the fixture or the constructor, but then I receive the pytest error

```
   def test_aMethod(newMyClass):
>      objectUnderTest = newMyClass.obj()
E      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'obj'
```

If fixtures can be used for this, how should that be coded?

Comment: Add a `return obj` in the fixture's body and use `newMyClass` directly. Fixture is evaluated before the test runs and the returned result is passed as test function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean up @hoefling's answer, you need to instantiate your class directly and return that instance. Check out this code if you're looking for a cleaned up version.

```py
import pytest

class MyClass():
  def __init__(self, obj, foo):
      self.obj = obj
      self.foo = foo

@pytest.fixture
def newMyClass():
    myClassInstance = MyClass(1,2)
    return myClassInstance

def test_aMethod(newMyClass):
    objectUnderTest = newMyClass.obj
    assert objectUnderTest
```

Comment: This works. However, a new object is provided to each `test_` method that references `newMyClass`. I typically want to evaluate how methods act collectively given a specific starting state, so this particular idiom does not achieve that.

Comment: Instead of a fixture, what about instantiating an object at file scope and referencing it in a `test_` method with `global myClassInstance`?  Or is there a way to use a fixture to achieve that result?  If so, why is using a fixture for this preferable?

Comment: Ah you change the scope of the fixture itself. If you do `@pytest.fixture(scope='session')` that will pass the instance of newMyClass.obj to every tests using that fixture.